# ODBC on Linux VM Instance

Tags: linux, terminal, odbc

I have a python script that I want to place on a Linux VM running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

The python script requires an ODBC driver to connect to a SQL Server.

I installed the ODBC drivers to the machine following Microsoft's instructions found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

Whenever I run `odbcinst -j` I get

```
unixODBC 2.3.6
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/~/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

However when I try to locate the drivers, they can't seem to be found. All of the data sources/drivers above return "no location" when I try to locate. Furthermore, running `ls -a /etc/` shows that `obdc.ini` and `obdcinst.ini` are file archives.

Is there any way to locate where the driver libraries are stored so I can link that to my script?

Comment: I assume that you have files in `/etc/ODBCDataSources` ?

Comment: That's the issue I'm encountering: there is no path `/etc/ODBCDataSources`

Comment: I would guess that `sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17` failed in some way. Ensure you have all the packages installed as per your instructions, and that some (probably this one) has files in `/etc/ODBCDataSources`. If the ODBC drivers are installed elsewhere, either update the config or link them here.